# Send automatic mail to Admin when user/member changes/adds profile

Tags: admin, email, updates, automation, profiling

Is there a way to send the updated/added values from profile, when a member/user updates his/hers data, to the admin of the site or another emailadress?

Can this be the first step?

```
/* do something when user edits profile */
add_action('personal_options_update', 'notify_admin_on_update');
function notify_admin_on_update(){
  // send a mail with the updated values to admin@mysite.com
  exit;
}
```

What is best pracice to send emails from within WordPress?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you got the first part right about using `personal_options_update` but to be on the safe side add `edit_user_profile_update` also.
and as for sending emails within WordPress the best way would be to use [**wp_mail**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail), So something like this:

```
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'notify_admin_on_update' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update','notify_admin_on_update');
function notify_admin_on_update(){
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();

    if (!current_user_can( 'administrator' )){// avoid sending emails when admin is updating user profiles
        $to = 'admin@email.com';
        $subject = 'user updated profile';
        $message = "the user : " .$current_user->display_name . " has updated his profile with:\n";
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
            $message .= $key . ": ". $value ."\n";
        }
        wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your if statement will assign `1` as the current user id, thus making anybody who updates a profile temporarily an administrator. Instead of using user id numbers, it makes more senese to check for permsissions: `if( !current_user_can( 'administrator' ) )`

Comment: Thanks, Bainternet and John P Bloch!
I used:
`if ($current_user->ID != 1){ `

Comment: I have a second question to this issue:

Comment: I have a second question to this issue:
The above suggestions works well but I want to only show/email the data that was updated, not all of the users data. And is it possible to email the data when a specific field has been updated.

Comment: that going to be hard since you don't have  a compression point for what the data was before the update, but you can.

Comment: @Bainternet: What is a "compression point" exactly? You mean another database entry to compare with?

Comment: No i mean the previous value before it was updated.

Comment: OK, I was afraid that it was not so easy to accomplish..

Comment: An old answer, but thought I would mention that you cannot assume that the administrator is user ID 1. The administrator may have been changed for various reasons: adding a new one, removing an old one, etc. But I like this answer.