# Send mail to wordpress admin

Tags: email

I have a page on my wordpress site that has some fields to be filled by visitor. On the click event of 'submit' button, all the details filled by visitor should be mailed to the wordpress admin.

I got to know how to [Send automatic mail to Admin when user/member changes/adds profile](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12193/send-automatic-mail-to-admin-when-user-member-changes-adds-profile)

but i don't have anything to do with the profiles right now. I want to send a mail to wp admin simply on button-click. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can achieve this using WordPress AJAX http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins. Try it and let us know if you face any problem.

Comment: You are welcome, also post your working answer here  and accept it so that it can help others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could not really work out with the ajax with plugins things. Not so good with it still. :( 
So i simply used the function `get_bloginfo('admin_email')` to obtain the admin's email address. Using `mail()` function, the mails are sent to the obtained email address on click of the button.